# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: HEAD. - laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I just installed laravel 8 with jetstream and all was working fine. I called login and register routes they are also working fine but when I am accessing root url it is giving me this error. i.e.

```
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: HEAD.
```

Don't know what is wrong with it
I ran many commands those are

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan view:cache
php artisan config:cache
```

My route is having this code

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Artist\AlbumController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Artist\TrackController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Artist\DashboardController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Artist\ArtistController;

Route::get('/', function () { return view('login'); });

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->name('dashboard');
```

Don't know why I am getting this error

Comment: can you try adding the middleware after get not before, in the laravel docs the middleware is after the get method and it's before the group method.

Comment: do you happen to be running different versions of PHP on this system? also just leave the routes uncached while developing `php artisan route:clear`, no need to cache them

Comment: @lagbox You guessed it right, After running ``php artisan route:clear``. It is working fine now.